# Roots to a Special Homogeneous Polynomial Equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of polynomial equations:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n&=&0 \\
x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2&=&0 \\
&\vdots & \\
x_1^n+x_2^n+\cdots+x_n^n&=&0
\end{array}\right.
$$
Obviously $X=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(0,\ldots,0)$ is a root. But is this the only one in $\mathbb{C}^n$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex plane. In other words, does there exist a non-zero root to the system?

Answer (score 2):

Due to [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) all [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) on $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are also zero. Therefore, by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $x_1,x_2,..., x_n$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^n=0$.

Hence, all of them are zero.

---

Define $$e_k=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}...x_{i_k}$$

These are called the elementary symmetric functions on the variables $x_1,...,x_n$.

They appear in the Vieta's formulas as the coefficients of a monic polynomial in terms of its roots.

$$P(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)=x^n-e_1x^{n-1}+e_2x^{n-2}+....+(-1)^ne_n$$

The polynomials that you have in your equations are also symmetric. Often denoted as $$p_k=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^k$$

Newton formulas allow you to relate the values of $e_1,...,e_n$ to the values of $p_1,...,p_n$. Since your system of equations is saying that all the $p_k$ are zero, for $k=1,...,n$, then the Newton identities tell you that also $e_1=e_2=...=e_n=0$. But then you see that the polynomial $P(x)$, of which $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are roots, is equal to $P(x)=x^n$.

Since this polynomial only has $x=0$ as a root, it follows that $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=0$.

Comment: @soiralstotheleft, thanks first, but can you give me a few more words to go on. Your argument does not compute immediately in a muddy mind like mine.

Comment: @StudentofStatistics Follow the links. Newton identities tell you how to compute from, for example $x_1+x_2+x_3$, $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$, and $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$, the values of $x_1+x_2+x_3, x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$, and $x_1x_2x_3$. But the latter are the coefficients of the polynomial $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$. If the first set of polynomials is zero, the second set is also zero, and therefore, this polynomial has all coefficients except for the leading one equal to zero, i.e. it is the polynomial $x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Alt.hint: consider the linear system in $\,u_1x_1, u_2x_2, \ldots,u_nx_n\,$:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
1 \cdot u_1x_1+1 \cdot u_2x_2+\ldots +1 \cdot u_nx_n &=&0 \\
x_{1}\cdot u_1x_1+x_{2}\cdot u_2x_2+\ldots +x_{n}\cdot u_nx_n&=&0 \\
&\vdots & \\
x_{1}^{n-1}\cdot u_1x_1+x_{2}^{n-1}\cdot u_2x_2+\ldots+x_{n}^{n-1}\cdot u_nx_n&=&0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Assuming not *all* $\,x_i\,$ are $\,0\,$, the system has the non-trivial solution $\,u_1=u_2=\ldots=u_n=1\,$, so its determinant must be $\,0\,$. But the respective determinant is a [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) which evaluates to $\,\prod_{1 \le i \lt j \le n} (x_j-x_i)\,$, so it can only be zero if $\,x_i=x_j\,$ for some pair $\,i \ne j\,$.

Assume WLOG that $\,x_{n-1}=x_{n}\,$, then consider:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
1\cdot u_1x_1+1 \cdot u_2x_{2}+\ldots +1 \cdot u_{n-1}x_{n-1} &=&0 \\
x_{1}\cdot u_1x_1+x_{2}\cdot u_2x_2+\ldots +x_{n-1}\cdot u_{n-1}x_{n-1}&=&0 \\
&\vdots & \\
x_{1}^{n-2}\cdot u_1x_1+x_{2}^{n-2}\cdot u_2x_2+\ldots+x_{n-1}^{n-2}\cdot u_{n-1}x_{n-1}&=&0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Again, if not *all* $\,x_i\,$ are $\,0\,$, then $\,u_1=u_2=\ldots=u_{n-2}=1, u_{n-1}=2\,$ is a non-trivial solution, which implies that another pair of $\,x_i=x_j\,$.

It follows by induction that all $\,x_i\,$ must be equal, and therefore all must be $\,0\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a nonzero solution. If some variables are zero, forget them. If two variables are equal say $x_1=x_2$ replace 
$x_1^m+x_2^m+\cdots$ by $2x_1^m+\cdots$, or more generally,  $n_1x_1^m+\cdots$ if there are $n_1$ many variables equal to $x_1$. This leads to having the system $x_1,\ldots , x_k$ of distinct and nonzero numbers such that  $$n_1x_1+\cdots +n_kx_k=0$$
$$n_1x_1^2+\cdots +n_kx_k^2=0$$
$$\vdots$$
 $$n_1x_1^k+\cdots +n_kx_k^k=0$$ for some multiplicities $n_1,\ldots ,n_k$ then

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1&\cdots &x_k\\
&\vdots&\\
x_1^k&\cdots&x_k^k
\end{vmatrix}=0$$ contradicting the assumption.

Comment: @ Rene, not following. More text? Thanks.

Comment: @StudentofStatistics This doesn't answer your question. The assumption is not the negation of the existence of non-zero solutions, and the conclusion doesn't contradict your equations. This argument is all wrong. It is not your fault that you are not following.

Comment: Made some edits, hope the argument is clear now.